# How to commit the same commands again through Metal?

Tags: metal

For example, I have an array of floating point numbers.

I run the `compute kernel` on them, write into it, and then I want to run the compute kernel again on the modified array.

How could I do that? Can I simply call `commit` again on the `commandBuffer`? Or do I need to encode all over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to reuse a command encoder or command buffer in Metal.